# VB Window Services batch not executing

Tags: windows, batch-file, vb6

I am executing a batch file by using VB run method to connect ftp.
When I am executing VB code in debugging mode batch file is executing without any issue and ftp is successful. But, after building the exe file and tried to run it thorough windows service batch file is not executing.

```
command = Chr(34) & "FTPconnection.bat" & Chr(34) & " " & moReportFile
a.Run command, 0, True
```

Comment: Can you please post some code?

Comment: Hi below lines are the code for executing batch file in vb.
                  command = Chr(34) & "FTPconnection.bat" & Chr(34) & " " & moReportFile
                      a.Run command, 0, True

Comment: It's possibly a working folder issue.  Try fully qualifying the path to ftpconnection.bat in your code.

Comment: Services don't have access to the network by default. That means no internet access, which means no ftp.

Comment: Try to run the FTPconnection.bat as the user of the windows service.

Comment: Hi all, Thanks for the all comments. Im running with fully qualifying path and running as the user of windows service.Services is not picking up the .bat file..Even, I tried with some other test code.Then also it's not working. Here, I am sharing the code and full details.I am trying to run test.bat file from VB code using run method.Below lines are the VB code.file_name = "E:\Email Service\test.bat" command Chr(34)&file_name & Chr(34) a.Run command, 0, True..Using .bat file I am trying to print hello in a text file..Below line is the bat file code.
echo hello >> 3.txt..

Comment: While I am running it normally code is able to create 3.txt but, unable to create with services. I am missing something. Please help me with this.